# When I use ssh to start remote program, error can't find shared libraries

Tags: c++, bash, shell, ssh, remote-access

I want to write a script to start the remote program, like this `ssh user@ip "/home/xx/remote_program"`(I used `ssh-copy-id` first).

I tested using `ssh user@ip "date"`, and I can get the remote date time. And I can `ssh user@ip`, then `./remote_program`, to start `remote_program`, run ok.

But when I use `ssh user@ip "/home/xx/remote_program"`, it tells me an error while loading shared libraries: libxmlrpcpp.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`.

I test to use `ssh user@ip "echo $PATH` and `ssh user@ip "echo $LD_LIBRART_PATH"`, the output same as `ssh user@ip` then `echo $PATH` `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

How can I start a remote program whit ssh script?

---

Thanks, @user1934428, you give me some inspiration.

I tested `printenv | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and there have many outputs, but when I use `ssh user@ip "printenv | grep LD_LDBRARY_PATH"`, the output is empty.

Today I did more tests.

I write a script in the remote machine,`start.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
source env.sh
cd build
./demo
```

If I execute `/home/xx/demo_dir/start.sh` in remote machine, run is ok.

But if i execute `ssh user@ip "/home/xx/demo_dir/start.sh"`, it tells me

```
/home/xx/demo_dir/start.sh: line 2: env.sh: No such file or directory
/home/xx/demo_dir/start.sh: line 3: cd: build: No such file or directory
/home/xx/demo_dir/start.sh: line 4: ./demo: No such file or directory
```

I'm confused about that, just like this command was executed in my local machine, not in the remote machine.

Comment: In this case, the double quotes don't make sense here. To verify the library path, do a `printenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of a `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: Where is libxmlrpcpp.so installed on the remote system? Do you have to set any environment variables on the remote system for programs to find the file? Where/how are those environment variables set?

Comment: Have you created the same directory structure on the other machine?  Did you copy `env.ch` and create the `build` directory?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I didn't create the `env.sh` or `build` in my local machine, they only exist in the remote machine. Because I want to execute the command in the remote machine, not locally.

Comment: Where did you create them?  Your script is going to start executing in `/home/xx`.  Do you, perhaps, need to do `cd demo_dir` at the start of your script?

Comment: @TimRoberts, you're right, thanks man, I will add an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I find the real reason for this phenomenon when I use the `ssh user@host command`, the bash mode is `non-interactive + non-login shell`.

So I fix my command like this

```
ssh user@host "source ~/.profile; source ~/.bashrc; cd /home/xx/test; source env.sh; cd build; ./demo;"
```

Run ok.